# can i acess res object in multer custom storage engine _handleFile function

Tags: node.js, express, multer

i need to acess the **res** object in multer custom storage engine **_handleFile** function is there any way? currently there is only **req**, **file**, **cb**

```
MyCustomStorage.prototype._handleFile = function _handleFile (req, file, cb) {
  this.getDestination(req, file, function (err, path) {
    if (err) return cb(err)

    var outStream = fs.createWriteStream(path)

    file.stream.pipe(outStream)
    outStream.on('error', cb)
    outStream.on('finish', function () {
      cb(null, {
        path: path,
        size: outStream.bytesWritten
      })
    })
  })
}
```

there is no **res** object to acess

Comment: Add another parameter and pass it from where _handleFile is called. I see the function copies a file to another based on the request. Why do you need the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `res` object is available under `req.res`. You can test it yourself:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.res === res); // true
  next();
})
```

I didn't find any documentation, but you can see the source [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/e1b45ebd050b6f06aa38cda5aaf0c21708b0c71e/lib/middleware/init.js#L31).